# set @RequestMapping value to return spring controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, mapping

I have problem with mapping in spring 3 mvc. General I must "send" value (@RequestMapping(value = "/*") to my return statement. How it resolve? I was thinking about this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/*", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String homeForm( Model model, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException  {
    logger.info("Welcome ");
    String url=response.getWriter().toString();
            return url;
}
```

Is it good solutions, maybe someone has any advices? 
Thaks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return the string that comes after the slash, you could do something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{foo}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String homeForm(@PathVariable("foo") String foo) {
    return foo;
}
```